# Error on enabled probe: syscall::open_nocancel:entry): invalid user access in action #2 at DIF

Tags: kernel, osx, dtrace

I've the following one-liner to show files opened by process:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s",execname,copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

however I've plenty of repeated errors such as:

> `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 4 (ID 946: syscall::open_nocancel:entry): invalid user access in action #2 at DIF offset 24`
>
> `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 7 (ID 160: syscall::open:entry): invalid user access in action #2 at DIF offset 24`

I'm aware that I can suppress them by redirecting to `2> /dev/null`.

What these errors means and why they're happening?

Is it `dtrace` fault, or some specific process causing that? And how this problem can be addressed?

I'm using OS X 10.11.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is potentially related to El Capitan and its System Integrity Protection (`csrutil status`) which can affect the `dtrace` behaviour.

The potential fix includes rebooting Mac into recovery mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> at boot time), then in Terminal run:

```
csrutil enable --without dtrace
```

to keep SIP enabled, but disable  DTrace restrictions (note: this is [undocumented parameter](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17452)).

Or disable SIP completely by:

```
csrutil disable # Not recommended.
```

See:

- [What is the “rootless” feature in El Capitan, really?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193368/22781) at Apple.SE
- [How do I disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208478/22781)